# Use LaTeX code in questions and answers (MathJax)?

Tags: feature-request, formatting

[physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) has this nice feature that allows you to enter LaTeX code (formulas) in questions and answers, and then renders it using MathJax. e.g. you enter `$x^2$` and it turns it into something like *x*². I was really surprized that it doesn't work on tex.SE.

Now, it wouldn't be useful for many questions, like ones that ask about preambles and specific packages, or page layouts. It also seems a majority of questions is actually about tikz, for which it wouldn't help either. However, I can see it very useful when discussing formulas.

It might be problematic to turn it on now, since many posts already have `$...$` in them. However, I think the conversion doesn't work inbetween backticks and in codeblocks, so it shouldn't cause many problems if the posts are properly formatted.

So, do we want this feature? And can we have it?

Comment: Please see [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1272) which explains why we don't have MathJax enabled on this site. Note that MathJax has been explicitly requested to be turned off ([Can we turn off math-tex please?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/181)) because it was originally enabled.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Ahh, I see. Sorry, I did a quick search before but didn't find anything on meta. Probably haven't been thorough enough.